# Should down votes require feedback?

Tags: feature-request, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we force adding a comment with every down-vote?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159/should-we-force-adding-a-comment-with-every-down-vote)

I'm here to help others by answering their questions to my best ability.

I feel like I'm contributing to the community. Some of my answers get down-voted with no feedback.

I believe that when somebody disagrees with your opinion, they should be required to leave their reason for down-voting. I'll be equally happy if reason is anonymous.

At the end of the day I'm here to share knowledge as much as learn. I don't normally ask questions, so when I get down-voted I would like to see some structured criticism explaining the down-vote.

Yes, often it's obvious why answer is down-voted, but this is not always the case and it would be nice to get some feedback.

What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: -1: Why should a downvote require an explanation if an upvote does not?

Comment: When you praise somebody you normally imply that person being praised did a good job. When you downvote someone, you want that person to improve, hence you give them the feedback or your opinion on a problem.

Comment: I don't think we should *require* feedback, but we should definitely encourage it, and users should lead by example by giving feedback when they downvote. I hate seeing new users post their first question, only to see a bunch of downvotes and no explanation as to why.

Comment: @Rachel Feedback is encouraged, there's a popup that asks new(ish) users to explain their down vote.

Comment: Adding comment for downvote requirement...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this Meta Stack Overflow question for more than you'll ever want to know on this subject:

[Encouraging people to explain down-votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)